# Как сделать, чтобы статическое изображение карты было в высоком разрешении?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/static/?um=constructor%3A9ee6a0e50b67ce405b5c4f6456fc1f24ca6d2fd7badf4dc9a27df3758a574915&amp;width=500&amp;height=342&amp;lang=ru_RU"
                    alt=""/>
```

Нужно изображение карты сделать по ширине резинового блока. Блок может быть больше 650px и потому карта выглядит размытой. Нужно изображение высокого качества. Здесь используется карта на 500px и потому уже видно размытие.

Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конструкторе карт https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/ можно скачать карту большого разрешения. Режим "Распечатать".